# Why does $-\frac{1}{17-x}$ equal $\frac{1}{x-17}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> Why does $-\frac{1}{17-x}$ equal $\frac{1}{x-17}$?

Is there any simple computation to make this seem a little bit more intuitive? Right now, I cannot wrap my head around the fact that I can just switch signs of the term in the denominator.

Comment: Using the original equation $$-\frac1{17-x}=\frac1{-1}\frac1{17-x}=\frac1{-17-\, - x}=\frac1{x-17}$$

Comment: You want it more intuitive. But intuition comes with experience. Learn why it's true, work with it, do similar exercises, and it will become part of your intuition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from the following algebra facts:

$$-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{-a}{b}=\frac{a}{-b}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
-(c-d) &= (-c)-(-d)\\
&=-c+d\\
&=d-c
\end{align}$$

(For this second fact we first "distribute the negative sign", and then "minus a negative is plus".)

Are you familiar with those manipulations? The person who wrote the text you got this from just combined a few steps into one equation.

Generally, unless you're first being introduced to such algebra, it's not considered necessary to write down every step - it's like they're saying "well, we start over here, and end up over there", and expect that you can fill in the details. And after a few times where you write it out explicitly, you'll find you can "do it with just your eyes", as you are reading along.

---

EDIT: (Since this is currently the accepted answer, I'll add another pattern that also sometimes shows up, and can be briefly puzzling, for the benefit of future readers.)

Similarly

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{-a}{-b}$$

is pretty obvious written that way, but can be harder to recognize when it's used to rewrite

$$\frac{1-x}{1-2x}$$
as $$\frac{x-1}{2x-1}$$

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful. For some reason I was thinking the whole time about -$\frac{a}{b}$ as $\frac{-a}{b}$ and not as $\frac{a}{-b}$.

Comment: It is equal to both/either. And yes, we usually do stick the minus sign in the top. But sometimes, like in this case, we get a nicer looking expression from sticking it on the bottom. You'll probably see this pattern again!

Answer (score 3):

$17-x=-1(x-17) $ so $(-1) (17-x) =(-1) ^2(x-17) =x-17$

Answer (score 3):

You can break this down into a couple of basic facts. First of all, we have $\frac{1}{-1}=-1$. Thus, if you want to see the *opposite*, or negative, of a fraction, we can multiply either the numerator or denominator by $-1$.

Secondly, and this might be the part you're really asking about, $a-b$ and $b-a$ are opposites. Observe: $$-1(a-b) = -a - (-b) = -a+b = b-a$$
Even better, think of numbers: What's $5-3$? What's $3-5$? To do the second computation, don't you just do the first one, and then include a minus sign, since the order was "wrong" for doing subtraction as an intuitive "take-away"?

Putting these together: to get the negative of a fraction, you can negate *either* the numerator or the denominator, and we choose the denominator. To negate a difference, you can just flip the subtraction statement around.

Does this help?

Comment: The observe line may need a few extra $a$ references...

Comment: @abiessu thank you

Comment: Yes, thank you! Writing it as $\frac{1}{-1}=-1$ helped me a lot.